# How can I create an external dictionary from url in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to create a dictionary from http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.csv
With this code:

```sql
CREATE DICTIONARY TestDict (
            registry String DEFAULT '',
            assignment String DEFAULT '',
            name String DEFAULT '',
            address String DEFAULT ''
        )
        PRIMARY KEY assignment
        SOURCE(HTTP(
            url 'http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.csv'
            format 'CSVWithNames'
        ))
        LAYOUT(FLAT())
        LIFETIME(300)
```

But when I try to `select * from default.TestDict` it returns error "Table default.testDict doesn't exist". And then dictionary status turns to "FAILED".
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's look at dictionary *last_exception*-param:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.dictionaries
FORMAT Vertical
/*
..
last_exception: Code: 27, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot parse input: expected , before: MA-L,002272,American Micro-Fuel Device Corp.,2181 Buchanan Loop Ferndale WA US 98248 \r\nMA-L,00D0EF,IGT,9295 PROTOTYPE DRIVE RENO NV US 89511 \r\nMA-L,086195,Rockw: (at row 1)

Row 1:
Column 0,   name: assignment, type: UInt64, ERROR: text "MA-L,00227" is not like UInt64
..
*/
```

The reason for the problem in the wrong selection of layout: [FLAT](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/dicts/external_dicts_dict_layout/#flat)-layout expects the numeric primary key with type UInt64 instead of String.

It needs to use [composite key](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/dicts/external_dicts_dict_structure/#ext_dict_structure-key) that support String-type and related [COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/dicts/external_dicts_dict_layout/#complex-key-hashed)-layout.

```sql
CREATE DICTIONARY TestDict
(
    registry String DEFAULT '', 
    assignment String DEFAULT '', 
    name String DEFAULT '', 
    address String DEFAULT ''
)
PRIMARY KEY registry, assignment, name
SOURCE(HTTP(URL 'http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.csv' FORMAT CSVWithNames))
LIFETIME(MIN 0 MAX 300)
LAYOUT(COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED())
```

Take into account that primary key consists of three columns *(registry, assignment, name)* to uniquely identify each row.

```sql
SELECT count()
FROM default.TestDict
/* result
┌─count()─┐
│   27742 │
└─────────┘
*/
```